# how to set range for a dynamic area and pasting with filters on in vba

Tags: dynamic, filter, range, copying, pasting

I'm having some trouble with a 2 step problem.

The first part is setting a range to constantly changing data. I've been trying to categorize claims on a worksheet that has data that is being added to the same sheet daily, so the last active cell keeps changing. For instance my issue with the specific line of code is as follows.

```
Columns(“D:D”).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 91).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Columns(“D:D”).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$EE$3000”).AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:= Array( _
    "DUPLICATE PAID/CAPTURED CLAIM:MORE CURRENT REFILL EXISTS", _
    "REFILL TOO SOON:CLAIM ALREADY PROCESSED FOR STORE, RX, DOS", _
    "REFILL TOO SOON:DISPENSED TOO SOON"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Columns(“A:A”).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

But I'm now recognizing setting the end range to a value of $EE$2007 isn't working. The column of EE will always remain the same, however the row changes.

The second part has to do with filtering. There are around 56 different categories in a separate column, V which then get flagged with a keyword in column A. I've gotten as far as being able to do the filtering portion and copying from the next cell up, but I'm having trouble pasting that keyword down the next which is the next blank cell and down to the last active row, again which all happens in column A. Above is what I have so far.

And this is where I get stuck. I'm new to all this, and am hoping to learn if there is a better way to go about this.

I was able to get to the second part by changing the range from $EE$2007 to $EE$3000 which caused my data to go further, but it is a possibility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Liz. Please provide code as it helps understand where you're coming from.